# How to reduce time complexity of this program

Tags: python, algorithm

The entry Y [i][j] stores the sum of the subarray X[i..j], but can I get a better time complexity?

```
def func(X, n):
    Y = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            for k in range(i, j+1):
                Y[i][j] += X[k]
    return Y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 500
    X = list(range(n))
    for i in range(30, 50):
        print(X[i], end=" ")
    print()

    print(func(X, n)[30][49])
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [prefix sum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-sum-array-implementation-applications-competitive-programming/) array.

The idea is that you have an array where the entry `ps[i]` denotes the sum of all elements `arr[0..i]`. You can calculate it in linear time:

```
ps[0] = arr[0]
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    ps[i] = ps[i - 1] + arr[i]
```

Can you guess how to retrieve a sum Y(i, j) in constant time?

**Solution:** `Y(i, j) = ps[j] - ps[i - 1]`. You take the entire sum of the array from j to the start and subtract the part that you don't want again (which is from i-1 to the start).
**Note:** It is possible that I messed up some edge cases. Be wary for things like i=0, j=0, j<i, etc.